# Get item from Django database model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to get the item from the database.
The problem is the item is saved as a list in Django. And item[i] is not helping either. Please help me figure it out how to get the data

in the shell, I have tried

```
for x in NewsItem.objects.all():
     print(x.tag)
```

this will print

```
['babi kutil', 'babi hutan', 'babi liar', 'hutan indonesia']
['ibu aniaya anak']
['pilkada serentak 2018', 'bandung', 'nurul arifin', 'pilwalkot bandung 2018']
['narkoba di surabaya', 'bnnp jatim']
['pilkada serentak 2018', 'banten']
```

But I want to get each item, not as a list.

The NewsItem Model.

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    breadcrumbs = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    penulis = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    judul = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    berita = models.TextField()
    tag = models.TextField(null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    @property
    def to_dict(self):
        data = {
            'data': json.loads(self.url),
            'tanggal': self.tanggal
        }
        return data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

Comment: Can you show `NewsItem` model?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Why is the data saved like that in the first place? It looks like the tag field contains a string representation of a list, which is not a very useful format.

Comment: it's because i don't know how to save them. this data is automatically insert into the database using scrapy pipeline. and i don't know how to split it into two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **2 for loops** to achieve this and as you have mentioned `tag` as **TextField**, so you need to split it on comma.

```
for x in NewsItem.objects.all():
     tag_text = x.tag[1:-1]
     tag_list = tag_text.split(",")
     for tag in tag_list:
         print(tag)
```

Comment: somehow they print each character so you get b,a,b,i, ,k,u,t,i,l not as a whole babi kutil

Comment: @ViraXeva, see the updated answer, as it is text field you need to split on comma.

Comment: it's work! but they seems to still have the bracket [ ] in the end. how to remove them?

Comment: @ViraXeva. check the updated answer. Now it will not contain `brackets`.